# XCOPY: Is there a way to only get one specific date?

Tags: xcopy

Is there a way in xcopy to get one specific date instead of the date and all files newer than the date in the /d:mm-dd-yyyy?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Vista/Win7/WinServer2008 you can use robocopy like so:

robocopy c:\source c:\destination *.* /MAXAGE:[ENDDATE] /MINAGE:[STARTDATE]

eg.

robocopy c:\source c:\destination *.* /MAXAGE:20130311 /MINAGE:20130101  (YYYY.MM.DD)

If you want just a single date just put these values as the same. If you want to copy specific
file types just change the *.* bit to *.docx for example to copy all word documents etc.

On XP, I'm not sure if there are built-in solutions short of using Powershell and the like.